# Ошибка при установке расширения в Brackets

Tags: плагин, обновление, расширения, adobe-brackets, brackets

Здравствуйте, недавно решил обновить версию Brackets'а до 1.8.
Все прошло успешно, но вот расширения и темы перестали устанавливаться!
Выдает ошибку ответа на которую я не смог найти :(
Никто не сталкивался с такой ошибкой?

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Такая же проблема, даже из zip-архива не устанавливаются. NodeJS обновлял и все равно не помогло

Answer (score 0):

попробуй обновить node.js
я скачал с офф. сайта - это решило проблему. 
https://nodejs.org/en/